# MATLAB/EXCEL Inverse Cumulative Distribution Function (ICDF) for Negative Binomial Distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, inverse, matlab, negative-binomial

I have some old MATLAB code that uses the `ICDF()` function call (inverse cumulative distribution function). I need to translate the following into an equivalent formula (or formulas) in Excel.  Here are specifics of the old MATLAB code that works (circa R2012b).  Unfortunately, I cannot currently run this MATLAB code and get a result.

```
X = RAND()

N = 745

A = 1

B = 1/(1+N)

Result = icdf( 'nbin', X, A, B )
```

---

The old MATLAB Docs state this: `Y = icdf(name,X,A,B)` computes the inverse cumulative distribution function for two-parameter families of distributions, where parameter values are given in `A` and `B`.

`A` is $r$: number of successes

`B` is $p$: probability of success in a single trial

---

I have obtained a function in Excel that will compute the Inverse Negative Binomial with the following arguments.

`NEGBINOM_INV(alpha, k, p)` = smallest integer $x$ such that `NEGBINOM.DIST(x, k, p, TRUE)` ≥ alpha. 
`NEGBINOM.DIST` is an Excel Function.

Key statistical properties of the negative binomial distribution are:

Mean = $k(1 – p) ⁄ p$

Variance = $k(1 – p) ⁄ p^2$

---

My specific question is what values are needed for the arguments of the `NEGBINOM_INV(alpha, k, p)` to duplicate the MATLAB `ICDF` function.

I have tried the following but am suspect of my argument values.

```
NEGBINOM_INV( RAND(), 1, 1/(1+745) )
```

TIA.

Comment: Is it absolutely necessary to do it within excel? Python has a library that allows one to work with excel: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/.  The ICDF can be computed using scipy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.nbinom.html

Comment: I will definitely check that out but the customer wants an excel spreadsheet model.  If someone could actually run the old MATLAB code and provide the answer it yields would also be a big help.